# Error running xcodebuild parallel jobs with same Cocoa Pod in frameworks & app

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcodebuild

We have an Xcode workspace (for an iOS app) which consists of multiple frameworks and a reference application which links to and uses the frameworks and the frameworks themselves as well as the reference application use the same pod (or pods).

I've created a simple application that exhibits the same error, it's up on Github (https://github.com/hds/ios-app-with-sdks). I'll just explain everything in terms on the sample application, as it should be easier to follow that way.

The project dependancy chart looks like this:

```
AppWithSDKs
 |- TheSDK
 |   |- ReactiveCocoa
 |- OtherSDK
 |   |- ReactiveCocoa
 |- ReactiveCocoa
```

ReactiveCocoa is one of the pods that I'm using in multiple places, so I've used in in the sample project as well. I don't think that ReactiveCocoa has anything to do with this error.

Building this project from the command line with `xcodebuild` produces a variety of errors, always related to the pod used in multiple parts of project. The most common error is in the code signing step, but I get errors related to setting file permissions and ownership as well. The errors always complain about the file that is to be signed (or have its permissions set) not being present.

The build command is:

```
xcodebuild -verbose -workspace AppWithSDK.xcworkspace -scheme AppWithSDK -sdk iphoneos8.4 -derivedDataPath Build -configuration Release archive -archivePath Build/Products/
```

An example of an error that I've seen is:

```
/usr/sbin/chown -RH <user>:<group> /path/to/project/AppWithSDK/Build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppWithSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/ReactiveCocoa.framework
chown: /path/to/project/AppWithSDK/Build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppWithSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Headers/UITextView+RACSignalSupport.h: No such file or directory
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

The suspicion is that `xcodebuild` is doing something in parallel that shouldn't be performed in parallel, but I don't know what that is. If we run `xcodebuild` with `-jobs 1` then there are no errors. The project also builds fine when it's compiled from the Xcode app.

Obviously the problem isn't a showstopper at the moment, but if we have to build in serial on the command line, it's going to make our Jenkins builds much slower.

Thanks in advance for any guidance or help.